# Particle JS – Calling a function which is part of an object

Tags: javascript, object

I know that normally to call a JavaScript function in an object you might do something like this (oops, edited):

```
var instance = function(){ 
    this.action = function (){
        alert('called');
    }
}

instance.action();
```

But I'm getting really confused with [Particles JS](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/). I call it as below:

```
p = particlesJS('particles-js', {
  ...
});
```

But if I console log *any* of the below its just undefined:

```
p
p.vendor.destroy()
p.fn.vendor.destroy()
```

What am I doing wrong? [Demo](http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/97e0b29042db5c69e78e1b516cc1e52f?editors=001)

Comment: You don't quite understand how functions work in JS. Try your top code out in a fiddle, it doesn't work. This is because action isn't addressable outside of instance. You would need to define it as `this.action = function(){...}` or `this.prototype.action = function(){...}`

Comment: `action()` as your code currently shows is the method often used to get "private" functions. Anything inside `instance` can use it but not outside.

Comment: And, as far as I can tell, particles.js doesn't have any public methods other than a constructor. Try deleting it from the dom by deleting `id='particles-js'`

Comment: Oops! Hmm, thats odd – I've found this one: https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/master/particles.js#L439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that's an odd interface.

I'm not entirely sure how he expects people to use particles.js... but to destroy it, you run the line:

```
pJS.fn.vendors.destroy();
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwyZaj

That's it. I'm assuming this only supports one particle canvas on the page at once.

And FWIW, most open source js libraries don't work this way.